# Updating the height and width of a Silverlight child element dynamically 

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, height, width

I'm facing this peculiar problem in my silverlight app. I have a Canvas that has a few Path elements. I need to load another UIElement on top of one of these Path elements. I have the code for it and it is all set.

The only problem I am facing is that I cannot update the Height and Width of these Path elements.

I was wondering if I could do something like this,

```
    (Path) this.canvas_name.Children[index].Height = height_of_a_UIElement;
    (Path) this.canvas_name.Children[index].Width  = width_of_a_UIElement;
```

It seems like even though I cast it I cannot access these properties.

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the datatype in Visual studio by pressing ctrl+shift+space when the cursor is between square brackets.It will help you to cast properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting the `Height` and `Width` properties, instead of the `Path` objects.  Try this:

```
((Path) this.canvas_name.Children[index]).Height = height_of_a_UIElement;
((Path) this.canvas_name.Children[index]).Width  = width_of_a_UIElement;
```

Comment: I cannot believe I was doing that! Thank you so much RobSiklos!!